# Can Eclipse C++ indexer be turned off on default

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, eclipse-neon

Can Eclipse (neon.3) C++ indexer be turned off automatically on IDE start?

My problem is that I need to restart Eclipse quite often, and with removal of all settings. Thus after such restart I need to enter preferences and add turn indexer off manually (and change some other stuff too). And if I forget that and import project, then Eclipse starts to work very slowly and another restart is necessary (full indexing takes couple of hours, depending on project).

Is there any possibility to set that on command line or some run command file?

If so, how deep into settings can it go? Adding new file type would be my next thought, but it's not as annoying as indexing one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu bar: `Window`->`Preferences`->`C/C++`->`Indexer`

Under "Indexing strategy" uncheck "Automatically update the index" and "Automatically update the index immediately after every file save".